# Compilation error using protobuf=3.4.0/3.6.1

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, object-detection

---

### Protocs files compilation

i am not getting this errors and want to resolve it .

**1. i tried protocs file compilation using both protobuf-3.6.1 and even for 3.4.0**

***Problem***

- i am getting the same issue - that the .protoc files that don't require any specific complied files they get complied easily
- but the .protocs files which needs 2 or more complied files they are
  not getting complied even after the subfiles are complied {as per
  image 2 will clearly shows this}

protobuf==3.4.0
[image]

protobuf==3.6.1
[image]

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]. Also don't post images of text. Your problem should be searchable by the next persons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run the below command from "research folder"

## From tensorflow/models/research/

protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.

Thanks,
Rajeswari Ponnuru

Comment: i got error "'protoc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: i also added protoc.exe to reserach folder then i got this error "protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
object_detection/protos/*.proto: No such file or directory"

Comment: Do not add protoc.exe to research folder. In the screen shot you have provided earlier, you were the command from "protos" folder. Please run the same command from research folder what you have run before. Use the absolute path for protoc.exe

Comment: Steps:

1>>  cd C:\Users\Prachi\Desktop\Tensorflow\models\research

2>> C:\Users\Prachi\Desktop\Tensorflow\protoc-3.6.1-win32\bin\protoc.exe object_detection\protos\anchor_generator.proto --python_out=.
 
i didnt wrote anything maunally , i copied path then paste it infact i even copied the .protocs file name also and paste 
&& if your geting the error for object_detection/protos file not found then copy the file name & paste it in prompt 
don't write manually you will get error of file not found or specific path not found .